# JPA with PostgreSQL 14 - Querying on LocalDateTime with atTime(LocalTime.MAX) overflows to next day

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am using spring boot 2.7 with spring data JPA / Hibernate 5.6.14 and PostgreSQL 14.

I have a mapping like this:

```
@Column(name = "column", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime column;
```

`column` is a  `timestamp` on the Database.

And I'm querying "column" with "between :initial and :final" where `:final` is

```
LocalDate.atTime(LocalTime.MAX);
```

Which is:

```
2023-02-27T23:59:59.999999999
```

But it returns dates like

```
2023-02-28T00:00:00.000000
```

My guess is that it's overflowing to the next day because the postgresql `timestamp` precision.

Is there a way to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. Based on my observations, postgres rounds timestamp to the nearest microsecond. One solution is to truncate the timestamp to microseconds:

```
LocalDate.atTime(LocalTime.MAX).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MICROS);
```

Another approach is to modify the query like this:

From:

```
<= LocalDate.atTime(LocalTime.MAX)
```

To:

```
< LocalDate.plusDays(1).atTime(LocalTime.MIN)
```